# modbus.ModbusIOException when trying to read multiple registers

Tags: java, modbus

When trying to read registers from a Modbus product using rtu, the console is outputting error: com.ghgande.j2mod.modbus.ModbusIOException: I/O failed to write.

I'm unsure why I am receiving a write error, when I am only attempting to read the product registers and not edit them, the code I am using is attached bellow.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ModbusSerialTransaction trans;
        ReadMultipleRegistersRequest req;
        ReadMultipleRegistersResponse res;
        SerialConnection con;

        int unitId = 1; // the unit identifier we will be talking to
        int repeat = 1; // a loop for repeating the transaction

        //Set Serial Parameters
        SerialParameters params = new SerialParameters();
        params.setPortName("COM37");
        params.setBaudRate("115200");
        params.setDatabits("8");
        params.setParity("none");
        params.setStopbits("2");
        params.setEncoding("rtu");
        params.setEcho(true);

        //Open the connection
        con = new SerialConnection(params); // set connection with parameters
        try {
            con.open();
            String isOpen;
            if(con.isOpen()) isOpen = "open"; else isOpen  = "closed";
            System.out.println("The connection " + con.getPortName() + " is " + isOpen);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Prepare a request
        req = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(0, 0);
        req.setUnitID(unitId);
        req.setHeadless();

        //Prepare a transaction
        trans = new ModbusSerialTransaction(con);
        trans.setRequest(req);

        System.out.println(trans.getResponse());

        try {
            int k = 0;
            do {
                trans.setTransDelayMS(500);

                trans.execute();

                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(req.getMessage()));

                res = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
                for (int n = 0; n < res.getWordCount(); n++) {
                    System.out.println("Word " + n + "=" + res.getRegisterValue(n));
                }
                k++;
            } while (k < repeat);
            //Close the connection
            con.close();
        } catch (ModbusException ex) {
            System.out.print(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I solved my issues, firstly params.setEcho(true) was supposed to be set to false. Secondly, ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(0, 0) sets the first register to read in param 1, and the number of register to read including that one after the value of the first register, something like ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(1, 10) would work correctly. The program should also call con.close(); on exception catch.